# Register 2D 360 rotation

Tags: game-physics, game-development, gdscript

How do I register 360 rotation of a 2D object?

I'd add the logic to the update function, and when the body does a 360 rotation, starting from 0, I'd emit a signal saying that the object did a 360.

In Godot terms we are talking about `_proces` or `_integrate_forces` for `RigidBody2D`.

My first idea is to create 2 arrays of angle checkpoints, and 2 variables for left and right 360s that would represent the current index of angle checkpoints, and if one of these variables gets to the maximum index (last angle checkpoint) then I could emit the 'body did a 360' signal.

Is there a less cumbersome way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**RUBBER DUCK HERE**

Here's how I did that. If you see how this can be optimized please post an answer and I'll flag it as one.

The only difference from my original idea is that, because when rotation is too fast the angle checkpoints were not detected, so I made each checkpoint a range instead of an exact angle

In my `RigidBody2D`, a car, I put this code:

```
signal Trick360
signal TrickLeft360
signal TrickRight360

const left_360_checkpoints = [[-10,0], [-140,-160], [0,10]]
const right_360_checkpoints = [[10,0], [140,160], [0,-10]]

var left_360_index = 0
var right_360_index = 0

func _process(delta):
    var int_rotation = int(rotation_degrees)
    
    for angle_range in left_360_checkpoints:
        var min_angle = min(angle_range[0], angle_range[1])
        var max_angle = max(angle_range[0], angle_range[1])
    
        if int_rotation > min_angle and int_rotation < max_angle:
            var new_index = left_360_checkpoints.find(angle_range)
            
            if abs(new_index - left_360_index) == 1:
                left_360_index = new_index
                
                if left_360_index == left_360_checkpoints.size() - 1:
                    left_360_index = 0
                    emit_signal("Trick360")
                    emit_signal("TrickLeft360")
                    
    for angle_range in right_360_checkpoints:
        var min_angle = min(angle_range[0], angle_range[1])
        var max_angle = max(angle_range[0], angle_range[1])
        
        if int_rotation > min_angle and int_rotation < max_angle:
            var new_index = right_360_checkpoints.find(angle_range)
            
            if abs(new_index - right_360_index) == 1:
                right_360_index = new_index
                
                if right_360_index == right_360_checkpoints.size() - 1:
                    right_360_index = 0
                    emit_signal("Trick360")
                    emit_signal("TrickLeft360")
```

Again, if you think this can be optimized, put your answer below, I'll flag is as the answer for this question. I think my code is heavy on the CPU even though I don't see any lagging or performance loss